# python script with reading lines, classes, arrays

Tags: python, arrays, class

Too general question so here is my edit:

I have a defined a class like this:

```
class person:
    name = ""
    value1 = 0
    value2 = 0
```

and I have file that contains lines like this

```
joe 1 2
mary 3 4
```

How can I read every line and create a class for (in this example)
`joe` with `value1` = 1 and `value2` = 2 and
`mary` with `value1` = 3 and `value2` = 4

Comment: I think you need to learn a bit about how Python classes work before you attempt to write this program. Maybe you should take a look at the material on classes in the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: I edit the question. Can you give now a helpful hint?

Answer (score 0):

I won't show you how to read the name strings and value integers from a file. But here's some code that will work on Python 2 or 3 that shows how to create your Person class & a couple of instances of that class.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, value1, value2):
        self.name = name
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Person("{0}", {1}, {2})'.format(self.name, self.value1, self.value2)

p1 = Person("joe", 1, 2)
p2 = Person("mary", 3, 4)

print(p1)
print(p2)
```

**output**

```
Person("joe", 1, 2)
Person("mary", 3, 4)
```